# Adding new column with the number of duplicates in R

Tags: r, duplicates

I have a column of ID's which have duplicates. What I want to do is create a new column which in each row divides 1 by the number of duplicates that exists of the ID in that column.

So for example in row 2 the ID is 101, in the same column the 101 is repeated three times. Therefore in a new column I want in row 2 to be 1 divided by the number of duplicates (1/3) of the 101 ID which gives a value of 0.33'. How would I go about this? Sorry if this doesn't make sense, happy to clarify.

Thanks so much in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `ave`:

```
# create data
set.seed(123)
ids <- sample(1:3, 10, replace = TRUE)
dat <- data.frame(id = ids)

#    id
# 1   3
# 2   3
# 3   3
# 4   2
# 5   3
# 6   2
# 7   2
# 8   2
# 9   3
# 10  1

# use ave to count instances of id
1/ave(dat$id, dat$id, FUN = length)

# 0.20 0.20 0.20 0.25 0.20 0.25 0.25 0.25 0.20 1.00
```

If your `id` variable is a character, we can use the `seq_along` function within our `ave` call:

```
dat$id <- as.character(dat$id)
1/ave(seq_along(dat$id), dat$id, FUN = length)
# [1] 0.20 0.20 0.20 0.25 0.20 0.25 0.25 0.25 0.20 1.00
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, works great! I was just wondering if you would know how to do the same calculation but with categorical/factor variables? So instead of the ID's being value they would be categories of colour etc,?

Comment: I have edited my answer to include that scenario.

Answer (score 0):

In the following code, I assume the data frame to be named `df`.

```
require("tidyverse")

df <- table(df$ID) %>%
   enframe() %>%
   mutate(value = 1 / value) %>%
   left_join(df, ., by = c("ID" = "name"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dat)[, value := 1/.N, id]
```

#### data

```
set.seed(123)
ids <- sample(1:3, 10, replace = TRUE)
dat <- data.frame(id = ids)
```